# Passing MySQL query via Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, post

In a Javascript function, I have the following JQuery in which I call a PHP script (i.e. getDBData.php) to get the database data from the query:

```
$("#dbcontent").load("getDBData.php", {query: "SELECT * FROM `texts` WHERE name='John' LIMIT 10;"});
```

In getDBData, I fetch this query via POST:

```
$query = $_POST['query'];
```

and give it as input for mysql_query:

```
$query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

However, I get the following MySQL error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'John\' LIMIT 10' at line 1*

What could be wrong here? I guess it has something to do with character encoding when passing the query, but don't seem to get it right.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: This is an **extremely** dangerous practice.

Comment: What if I decide to pass the `DELETE * FROM texts` query to your PHP script? What would prevent me from doing that? Are you sure that you still want to `mysql_query($query)` on it? Personally I wouldn't.

Comment: Horrible, horrible, horrible idea.

Comment: Just to reiterate, this is a terrible idea, but it seems to be failing because your quotes are being escaped.  Do you have magic quotes on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never do this under any circumstances.  You should be passing parameters that can then be used to build the proper query.

At least do something like this....

**Javascript**

```
$.post('getDBData.php', {
   query: 'getTextsByUser',
   user: 'John'
});
```

**PHP**

```
$queries = array(
   'getTextsByUser' => 'SELECT * FROM texts WHERE name = ?',
   'getNewsById' => 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ?'
);
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($queries[$_POST['query']);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['user']);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

And then pass `getUsers` via ajax to determine which query to run.

**Note:** If you're just beginning this project, [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) has been deprecated and you should consider switching to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do it this way, as others have pointed out! Webnet's solution is much better!**

But I believe I know how to solve your initial problem. I had it once too, when parsing JSON, and solved it by using `stripslashes()`.

```
$query = stripslashes($_POST['query']);
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

As many people have stated, this is very risky.  I think what's failing, however, is the fact you need to specify the query with URL encoding.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding.  This especially applies to the `=` symbol.

Comment: jQuery will correctly URL encode everything you pass as a key/value pair argument to the $.load function. You don't need to be doing any manual encoding.